# MVC 3 model item passed into dictionary error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I get this error and i don't understand why:
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Devart.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[CHRContext.WIKIIDEE]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'CHRContext.WIKIREPARTO'.

method from model

```
public IQueryable<WIKIIDEE> GetIdeasByDeptID(int id)
        {
            var query = from i in db.WIKIIDEEs
                        where i.IDREPARTO == id
                        select i;

            return query;
        }
```

method from controller

```
public ActionResult List(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            IdeeRepository ideeRepo = new IdeeRepository();

            IQueryable<WIKIIDEE> list = ideeRepo.GetIdeasByDeptID(id);

            return View(list);
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
```

and view

```
 @model IEnumerable<CHRContext.WIKIIDEE>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>List</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            IDREPARTO
        </th>
        <th>
            DATAINSERIMENTO
        </th>
        <th>
            DESCRIZIONE
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IDREPARTO)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DATAINSERIMENTO)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DESCRIZIONE)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: On what line do you get the error? in the controller?

Comment: when the foreach from the view finished itterating the elements

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar issue and was able to work around it.  You can see how, here in my answer: [The model item passed into the dictionary is of type A, but this dictionary requires a model item of type B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924507/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-a-but-this-dictionary-requ/10965969#10965969)