# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type A, but this dictionary requires a model item of type B

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model, view, viewmodel

Ok, there are a ton of questions like this and I've looked through about 1500lbs of it.  The ones that I saw, people were either sending the wrong type or they were doing something with a partial view.  I am doing neither in my case.  So, my exact error is:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'ClanSite.Models.ViewModels.CategoryViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ClanSite.Models.ViewModels.UserLoginViewModel'.

The issue is that I have a model on my _Layout.cshtml (@model ClanSite.Models.ViewModels.UserLoginViewModel) that is used to login in the user on every page.

But, on one of those pages, I am trying to render a list of Categories.  My CategoryViewModel only contains a List of Category, GetCategories() returns that List.

Controller

```
public ActionResult Categories()
    {
        CategoryViewModel cats = new CategoryViewModel();
        try
        {
            cats.Categories = ForumQueries.GetCategories();
        }
        catch
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Message", new { msg = "categories" });
        }
        return View(cats);
    }
```

View

```
@model ClanSite.Models.ViewModels.CategoryViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "clanSite - Categories";
}
<div class="forumPostTable">
@foreach (ClanSite.Models.Tables.Join.Category cat in Model.Categories)
{
    <div class="forumPostTableRow cursorPointer" onclick="linkTo('@Url.Action("Index", "Home")')">
        <div class="forumCategoryTableCellTitle">
            <div class="forumCategoryTitle">
                <a href="" class="linkNoDecGold">Title</a>
            </div>
            <div class="forumCategoryTitleDesc">
                @cat.CategoryInfo.Description
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
</div>
```

When I try to go to this page, I get the error.  I stepped through the page with the debugger and was getting the correct data in: @cat.CategoryInfo.Description

It's really confusing me because I was able to create a form for user registration on another page using the model without any issues.  So, how can I use a model in the _Layout and in a View in which I am just looping through the data for output?

Comment: Is your `_Layout` .cshtml requiring a specific @model Type?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean.  The _Layout.cshtml does have @model ClanSite.Models.ViewModels.UserLoginViewModel in it, which is used to submit a form to login the user.

Comment: I don't think you can mix specified @model types like that... hence the type mismatch.  You're basically asking the view engine to cast your `ClanSite.Models.ViewModels.CategoryViewModel` to a `ClanSite.Models.ViewModels.UserLoginViewModel`, which it cannot do.

Comment: So, try making your _Layout not be strongly-typed and see if that just works ;)

Comment: How would I do the form in the _Layout then?  Also, like I said, I am able to have the form in _Layout and on my Registration page, which uses _Layout, have another form, with both _Layout and Registration using different ViewModels.

Comment: Does your `Registration` View use a `UserLoginViewModel`?

Comment: No, it uses a different ViewModel.

Comment: Is that a subclass of `UserLoginViewModel`?

Comment: No, it is its own class.  It has no connection to UserLoginViewModel.

I would think this would be a rather common occurrence to have a model used in the _Layout and one in a view displayed in that _Layout's body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do have an application in MVC that also requires a good use of Models and my approach would be not to use a Model in the `_Layout.cshtml`. If there is such a case, like Login operations, needed in all pages and therefore defined in the `_Layout.cshtml`, a `RenderPartial` call should be used and a specific Model should be also created.

```
<section id="login">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_Login", new MyProjectName.Models.Account.LoginModel()); }
</section>
```

All the pages will have the Partial View available and with its proper Model. Normal Views can then be created and displayed in the `RenderBody()` tag inside `_Layout.cshtml` without any Model conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to get around this rather easily.  I just made an interface ILayout that only contains a public UserLoginViewModel member.  I then implement this interface in my CategoryViewModel.  Which means, I need to add UserLoginViewModel to CategoryViewModel, but this is not an issue at all.  The only thing I needed to change for logging in, was instead of sending UserLoginViewModel to the View from the Action that handles the logging in, I sent ILayout.